# How to use positive lookbehind to find only certain 3 digit numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I have this text where I want to identify only certain three digit numbers using my depart city (`NYC`) as the positive lookbehind expression. I don't want to include it or anything else in the result, other than the desired three digit number.

I can't simply use `\d{3,}` because there are other three digit numbers in this text I haven't included here which should not be in the output.

***Example string***:

```
Depart: NYC (etd 9/30), NJ (etd 10/4)
Arrive LAX
Rate: USD500, 700P
```

***My regular  expression***

```
(?<=NYC)(\D|\S)*\d{3,}
```

***Output***

```
 (etd 9/30), NJ (etd 10/4) Arrive LAX Rate: USD500, 700
```

However, I want it to output `700` only.

I've also tried

```
(?<=NYC)(?<=(\D|\S)*)\d{3,}
```

but this doesn't output anything.

Comment: Try `(?s)NYC.*\b(\d{3,})` or `(?s)NYC.*?\b(\d{3,})`

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/IvKziV, works as expected, `700` is the output.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I included my pattern as a variable, which made it not work originally: ` value =re.search(pattern1, string1, re.IGNORECASE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use

```py
(?s)NYC.*?\b(\d{3,})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VRend3/1). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - `re.DOTALL` inline modifier
- `NYC` - `NYC` word
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d{3,})` - Group 1: three or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IvKziV):

```py
import re
text = """Depart: NYC (etd 9/30), NJ (etd 10/4)
Arrive LAX
Rate: USD500, 700P"""
m = re.search(r'(?s)NYC.*?\b(\d{3,})', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))

# => 700
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `(\D|\S)` matches any character except a digit, or match any non whitespace char. This will match any character, and can also be written as `[\s\S]` or you can let the dot match any character using `(?s)` or with a flag `re.DOTALL`

To match the first occurrence of 3 digits only without using the USD as positive lookbehind, you can capture 3 digit that are not surrounded by digits:

```
^[\s\S]*?(?<!\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[\s\S]*?` Match any char including newlines, as few as possbiel
- `(?<!\d)` Assert not a digit to the left
- `(\d{3})` Capture 3 digits
- `(?!\d)` Assert not a digit to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3ArpE/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dx0rpj)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"^.*?(?<!\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)"
 
s = ("\"Depart: NYC (etd 9/30), NJ (etd 10/4)\n"
    "Arrive LAX\n"
    "Rate: USD500, 700P\"\n")
 
m = re.search(pattern, s, re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print (m.group(1))
```

To match the 700 after NYC, you can capture 3 digits preceded by a word boundary and assert no following digit

```
^[\s\S]*?\b(\d{3})(?!\d)
```

Output

```
500
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6EALPJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6HBcdE)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"^.*?\b(\d{3})(?!\d)"
s = ("\"Depart: NYC (etd 9/30), NJ (etd 10/4)\n"
    "Arrive LAX\n"
    "Rate: USD500, 700P\"\n")
 
m = re.search(pattern, s, re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print (m.group(1))
```

Output

```
700
```